# resolve JSON data that doesn't show up when called. in listview flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, listview

I am trying to display API data into a listview builder and when I try to call the data the response is 200 and there is no error.

[image]

however, the data does not appear when you want to display it to the user.
[image]

Is there anyone here who has had a problem like mine?
if so, how did you handle it?
Thank You.

and this is the function when i call data API

```
Future<NilaiMahasiswa> getNilaiMahasiswa() async {
    String url = Constant.baseURL;
    String token = await UtilSharedPreferences.getToken();
    final response = await http.get(
      Uri.parse(
        '$url/auth/mhs_siakad/transkrip_nilai',
      ),
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
      },
    );

    print(response.statusCode);
    print(response.body);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return NilaiMahasiswa.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
    } else {
      throw Exception();
    }
  }
```

the following is when I display the data to the user

```
class _NilaiMahasiswaPageState extends State<NilaiMahasiswaPage> {
  List? data = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Services().getNilaiMahasiswa();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(kToolbarHeight),
        child: CustomAppbar(
          title: 'Nilai Mahasiswa',
        ),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: data!.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) {
          return Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 12, right: 12, top: 12),
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                  Radius.circular(8),
                ),
                boxShadow: [
                  BoxShadow(
                    color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.2),
                    spreadRadius: 1,
                    blurRadius: 9,
                    offset: const Offset(
                      1,
                      2,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              width: double.infinity,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      data![index]["id_mk"],
                      style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 12,
                    ),
                    Text(
                      data![index]['nm_mk'],
                    ),
                  ],
                ), ...
```

and this model

```
class NilaiMahasiswa {
  String? status;
  String? code;
  List<Data>? data;

  NilaiMahasiswa({this.status, this.code, this.data});

  NilaiMahasiswa.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    status = json['status'];
    code = json['code'];
    if (json['data'] != null) {
      data = <Data>[];
      json['data'].forEach((v) {
        data!.add(Data.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
    data['status'] = status;
    data['code'] = code;
    if (this.data != null) {
      data['data'] = this.data!.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Data {
  String? idTranskripNilai;
  String? idMk;
  String? kodeMk;
  String? nmMk;
  int? sks;
  int? smt;
  String? nilaiAkhirUts;
  String? nilaiHurufUts;
  String? nilaiIndeksUts;
  String? nilaiAkhirUas;
  String? nilaiAkhir;
  String? nilaiHurufAkhir;
  String? nilaiIndeksAkhir;
  int? statusNilaiAkhir;
  int? statusNilaiUts;
  String? updatedBy;

  Data(
      {this.idTranskripNilai,
      this.idMk,
      this.kodeMk,
      this.nmMk,
      this.sks,
      this.smt,
      this.nilaiAkhirUts,
      this.nilaiHurufUts,
      this.nilaiIndeksUts,
      this.nilaiAkhirUas,
      this.nilaiAkhir,
      this.nilaiHurufAkhir,
      this.nilaiIndeksAkhir,
      this.statusNilaiAkhir,
      this.statusNilaiUts,
      this.updatedBy});

  Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    idTranskripNilai = json['id_transkrip_nilai'];
    idMk = json['id_mk'];
    kodeMk = json['kode_mk'];
    nmMk = json['nm_mk'];
    sks = json['sks'];
    smt = json['smt'];
    nilaiAkhirUts = json['nilai_akhir_uts'];
    nilaiHurufUts = json['nilai_huruf_uts'];
    nilaiIndeksUts = json['nilai_indeks_uts'];
    nilaiAkhirUas = json['nilai_akhir_uas'];
    nilaiAkhir = json['nilai_akhir'];
    nilaiHurufAkhir = json['nilai_huruf_akhir'];
    nilaiIndeksAkhir = json['nilai_indeks_akhir'];
    statusNilaiAkhir = json['status_nilai_akhir'];
    statusNilaiUts = json['status_nilai_uts'];
    updatedBy = json['updated_by'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
    data['id_transkrip_nilai'] = this.idTranskripNilai;
    data['id_mk'] = this.idMk;
    data['kode_mk'] = this.kodeMk;
    data['nm_mk'] = this.nmMk;
    data['sks'] = this.sks;
    data['smt'] = this.smt;
    data['nilai_akhir_uts'] = this.nilaiAkhirUts;
    data['nilai_huruf_uts'] = this.nilaiHurufUts;
    data['nilai_indeks_uts'] = this.nilaiIndeksUts;
    data['nilai_akhir_uas'] = this.nilaiAkhirUas;
    data['nilai_akhir'] = this.nilaiAkhir;
    data['nilai_huruf_akhir'] = this.nilaiHurufAkhir;
    data['nilai_indeks_akhir'] = this.nilaiIndeksAkhir;
    data['status_nilai_akhir'] = this.statusNilaiAkhir;
    data['status_nilai_uts'] = this.statusNilaiUts;
    data['updated_by'] = this.updatedBy;
    return data;
  }
}
```

Comment: can you add your model from JSON method code if you're converting data to the model why you are displaying with the JSON ??

Comment: i've update this question

Comment: Where you store your response in List data = []

Comment: your state manager ?

Comment: @K K Muhammed Fazil i'm not use state management

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this code.

```
  List<Data> data = [];
  
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fetchData();
  }

  fetchData()async{
    final apiResponse = await Services().getNilaiMahasiswa();
    setState(() {
      data.addAll(apiResponse.data!);
    });
  }
```

Comment: how do i call it in text?
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DZp7ahPPqcPNHR6CgmZ_9g7231ky5Rpd/view?usp=share_link

Comment: data[index].idMk

Comment: it works, thanks @K K Muhammed Fazil

Answer (score 1):

```
NilaiMahasiswa? responseData;

@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getResponseData();
  }

getResponseData()async{
 final response = await Services().getNilaiMahasiswa();
  responseData = response.data; //if response isn't work then use **response** only.
}
```

Then in your **ListView.builder** use responseData.

Hope it will work.

Comment: like this
 itemCount: responseData!.data!.length,

Comment: Text(
                      responseData!.data[index]["id_mk"],
                      style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                    ),

Comment: and an error occurs when I try

Comment: in getReponseData method try print the response that is it working. after that if data call done then use responseData?.data?.length ?? 0 . because of null safety

Comment: sorry, it doesn't work well for me